# If aqeeqa of of newly born child is not performed and the child die unfortunately. Is aqeeqa is still obligatory?

Tags: aqeeqah

It is Sunnah  that for a newly born child aqeeqa is performed on the seventh day  of child birth. But if a parent are not able to perform this sunnah to due some financial issue or some other reason and the child died unfortunately is it necessary for  parent for perform aqeeqa after child death.

Answer (score -2):

It isn't necessary for a parent to perform aqeeqa.

Comment: We require answers here to be well elaborated focused on answering the question asked and any claims to be supported by evidences: See [answer].